# WlanOpenHandle fails with error code 1062

Tags: windows, ssid

I am using the native Wifi Api to fetch the ssid on windows 8 machine but the "WlanOpenHandle" call always fails with the error code 1062. Any help?

Note: there is no wzc service on windows 8.

Comment: Error 1062: The service has not been started.  Perhaps the service has a different name in Windows 8, or perhaps the machine you're working on doesn't have the necessary feature(s) installed?

Comment: what are the required features? the documentation does not seem to mention any!

Comment: Whatever feature includes the wzc service.  Alternatively, it may be that the wzc service doesn't exist at all in Windows 8.  What are you setting the `dwClientVersion` argument to?

Comment: It looks like the corresponding service is called "WLAN AutoConfig", is that service installed and running?

Comment: thanks a lot, it was there but i had to manually start it!! call succeeded after that

Answer (score 9):

As confirmed by the OP, the proximate cause of the error was that the service "WLAN AutoConfig" was not running.  This requirement does not seem to be documented; I've added a note in the community contributions section.