# The service has not been started

Tags: c#

I use this [NativeWifi](https://github.com/consp1racy/NativeWifi) library to get the name of WiFi.

I'm testing with VMWARE and I get an exception:

> Message: "The service has not been started"
>
> NativeErrorCode: 1062.
>
> Source: "ManagedWifi";

Follow code:

```
try
{
    WlanClient wlanClient = new WlanClient();  //   <--------------   problem is here

    List<String> list = new List<String>();

    foreach (WlanInterface wlanInterface in wlanClient.Interfaces)
    {
        if (wlanInterface.InterfaceState == Wlan.WlanInterfaceState.Connected)
        {
            Wlan.Dot11Ssid ssid = wlanInterface.CurrentConnection.wlanAssociationAttributes.dot11Ssid;
            list.Add(new String(Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(ssid.SSID, 0, (int)ssid.SSIDLength)));
        }
    }

    return list.FirstOrDefault();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return $"Error: {ex.Message}";
}
```

The problem occurs on the line: `WlanClient wlanClient = new WlanClient();`.

This problem happens in the virtual machine (VMware).

Any Solution ?

Comment: What wireless network adapter is configured in your VM? Can you manually connect to a wireless network in your VM?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean Yes set to "Bridge Mode".

Comment: I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333171/wlanopenhandle-fails-with-error-code-1062

Comment: Did that resolve your issue?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean Yes, I'm calm now.

Comment: You could have looked into the code and found out that the constructor makes a pinvoke call to `WlanOpenHandle()` which exists in (wlanapi), then look it up on the MSDN and find this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706759(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa Thanks for the info.